# Trying to group similar names in an Excel spreadsheet using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am helping my employer sort some data for a screen-printing shop and we write multiple invoices for the same client. He would like to combine the sales data for the clients as a single row, which I can do manually but I wanted to write some code to group up the clients with the exact same name. I am fairly new to python but have a decent amount of experience with programming, specifically Java.

Here is my program:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

wb = load_workbook(r'C:\Users\owner\Downloads\Invoices Overall.xlsx')
source = wb.active
ws = wb.copy_worksheet(source)


for row in range(1, ws.max_row):
    char = get_column_letter(2)
    s = ws[char + str(row)].value
    i = 0
    while s == ws[char + str(row + 1)].value:
        if s != ws[char + str(row + i)].value:
            break
        else:
            ++i
        ws.row_dimensions.group(row, row + i + 1, 1, True)
        print(ws[char + str(row + i)].value)
        ws.insert_rows(i + 1)
        ws.insert_rows(i + 1)

ws.save('Invoices_Test_Copy.xlsx')
```

I have it written to output the names that it is grouping so that I can see that it's working but it is currently outputting just the first line. Thanks for any help, in advance.

Comment: Consider using the openpyxl API for the task. Then add some print statements to check your assumptions as you go but it is probably easier to get the bounds of the rows for each client name first and then group by row and insert rows (from the bottom) as required.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you'd use something like a database to do your grouping for you and then interrogate it for the boundaries. We don't know exactly the structure you have but the following gives you a generic approach. You will need to check that this is doing what you want it to and adjust as necessary.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
clients = defaultdict(list)

# Compile a dictionary of the rows for each client
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_col=2, max_col=2):
    cell = row[0]
    clients[cell.value].append(cell.row)

# loop over the clients, group by the boundaries and insert rows
for k, v in reversed(clients.items()): # start at the end of the sheet
    first_row, last_row = min(v), max(v)
    ws.row_dimensions[first_rows].group(first_row, last_row, 1, True) # not quite sure what you want to do here.
    ws.insert_rows(last_row, 2) # insert two empty rows below
```

Comment: ' ws.row_dimensions[first_rows].group(first_row, last_row, 1, True) # not quite sure what you want to do here.'

[This api reference](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.html?highlight=group) (scroll a bit) is where I got the formatting from but I deleted the 'end=value' because I wasn't sure if it was necessary. This is actually quite essential to what the function of the program is supposed to be because I want it to group the lines with the same name and hide the grouping.

Comment: Here is a few example cells for context:
\n 14269 (UGIA) Choose Gang Free Hat redo |
\n 14211 (UGIA) Choose Gang Free Blank Polos